# Get key/value from object, perform function and send back in

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am getting `[{id:'test', time: '1223'}, {id: 'test2', time: '2323'}]` from the backend, I need to retrieve the time values for all, perform a function and send back into the object as `[{id:'test', time: 'new value for test'}, {id: 'test2', time: 'new value for test2'}]`

So I decided I would try and extract the time values and push into array using `for loop` but my `for loop` is missing something

```
var objext = [{id:'test', time: 'blah'}, {id: 'test2', time: 'blah'}];
  var dataArray = new Array;
  for (var id  in  objext) {
    dataArray.push(objext[id]);
  };
```

It returns the same obviously as I don't know how to select the `time` key.

And then I'll run my function for each as such which is working well:

```
var time = [23,34,56];
  var map = time.map(function(num) {
    if (num === 23) {
      return num +2;
    } else {
      return num;
    };
  });
```

And then the final part will be to put back and I'm thinking I could get an array of `id` and one of `time` and then slot back in together but the code I have so far can only map one array at a time:

```
var data = ["Drake","Ola","d"],
    result = data.map(function (a) { return { id: a }; });
```

I have tried using an array as such:

```
var data = ["Drake","Ola","d"];
var hht = [21,34,56];
result = [data,hht].map(function (a,b) { return { id: a, time:b }; });
```

It did not map it properly.
Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to update `time` keys based on another array.

Comment: No, I'm updating `time` keys based on a function I created, I'll be getting the value and performing a function and slotting back in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform all of the tasks withing `.map()` callback

```
var objtext = [{id:'test', time: '1223'}, {id: 'test2', time: '2323'}];
objtext = objtext.map(function(obj) {
  var time = obj.time; 
  // do stuff with `obj.time`
  if (time == 1223) {
    time += 2;
    obj.time = time;
  }
  if (time == 2323) {
    time -= 2;
    obj.time = time;
  }
  return obj
});
```

To create an array containing only `time` properties

```
var times = objtext.map(function({time}) {return time});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array, iterate it and use from the other parts as well for a new object.

```js
var data = ["Drake", "Ola", "d"],
    hht = [21, 34, 56],
    result = data.map(function (a, i) { 
        return { id: a, time: hht[i] };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array of objects and return a different time with `Object.assign`:

```js
var objs = [
    {id: 'Drake', time: 'blah'}, 
    {id: 'Ola',   time: 'blah'}, 
    {id: 'd',     time: 'eh'  }];
var hht = [21, 34, 56];

objs = objs.map( (obj, i) => Object.assign({}, obj, { time: hht[i] }) );

console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `for` loop.

```js
var res = [{
    id: 'test',
    time: '1223'
  }, {
    id: 'test2',
    time: '2323'
  }, {
    id: 'test3',
    time: '2453'
  }],
  hht = [21, 34, 56];
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  res[i]["time"] = +res[i]["time"] + hht[i]; 
  //or use if statements 
  //if(+res[i]["time"] === 23)res[i]["time"] = +res[i]["time"] + hht[i];
 
  //scenario will be 
 //res[0]["time"] = 1223 + 21
 //res[1]["time"] = 2323 + 34
 //res[2]["time"] = 2453 + 56
}
console.log(res);
```